# Ссылка на изображение в Flask

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

Пытаюсь сделать вывод отчетов из базы postgresql в веб-интерфейс Flask.

Таблица reports

- Id
- date
- name
- work
- photo ARRAY

Поле `photo` содержит список имен фотографий, к примеру ['01.jpg','02.jpg'] в `/static/img/`

```
report = Reports.query.all()

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>date</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>work</th>
        <th>photo</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        { % for post in report % }
        <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ post.date }}</td>
        <td>{{ post.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ post.work }}</td>
        <td>{{ post.photo }}</td>
        { % endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>

>>>

|id |   date   |    name    |   work    |    photo             |
| 1 | 01.01.19 |   user1    |   test    | ['01.jpg', '02.jpg'] |
```

Использую:

```
<td>
{% for photo in post.photo %}
<a href="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/') }} {{ photo }}">Link 1</a>
<td>
```

Так я получаю ссылку `127.0.0.1:5000/static/img/%2001.jpg`
Подскажите пожалуйста,  как правильно подставить значение `photo` в `url_for`
И как можно для каждого значения увеличивать Link + 1?

Comment: `{% for photo in post.photo %}` и так далее?

Comment: Но это будет просто имена файлов, хотелось бы просматривать их через веб-интерфейс,  либо просто ссылки от 1, 2 , 3 где каждая на свою фотку, либо "Показать" где на странице сразу все фотки. Не могу именно в html понять как это делать.

Comment: `url_for` как и любые другие ссылки во Flask

Comment: Зачем мудрить, `{{ url_for('static', filename='img/' + photo) }}` и всё

Comment: И ещё `Link {{ loop.index }}`

Comment: Спасибо, большое. Вы очень мне помогли.